# Writing integer values into binary file

Tags: c, binary-data

Lets say I have an array numbers that contains the following values:

```
int numbers = [12, 511, 337, 254];
```

Now, I would like to scale those numbers into single byte values and store them in 
a char array

```
char numbersscaled;  

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {  
    numbersscaled[i] = numbers[i]/2;  
}
```

Finally, I would like to write those values as a binary file as follows:

```
filebin = fopen("results.bin", "wb");  

if(file==NULL) {   
    printf("Error\n");  
    return 1;  
}  

fwrite(numbersscaled, sizeof(numbersscaled[0]),
         numbersscaled/numbersscaled[0], filebin);  

fclose(filebin);
```

Unfortunately, when trying to compile this program gcc does not like the fwrite command:

```
error: invalid operands to binary / (have ‘char *’ and ‘int’)
```

Anyone an idea what I am missing?
Thanks!

Comment: you're converting an int to a char... why allow the value to be larger than can be fit into a byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're missing `sizeof`.

```
sizeof(numbersscaled)/sizeof(numbersscaled[0])
```

Note that there are many typos in your question (missing `[]`, etc), making it hard to detect the real problem. Please fix it.

Comment: thanks, that is it. Sorry it is early in the morning, so completly awake yet ;)

Comment: Good, should get better as you drowse back to the normal wakeful sleepiness :-)

Answer (score 0):

numbersscaled should be array of chars not char.

```
fwrite(numbersscaled, sizeof(numbersscaled[0]), 4, filebin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is not right with,

```
numbersscaled/numbersscaled[0]
```

Isn't it `char numberscaled[4]`? tho you have declared it as a char in your question.

You should read the `fwrite` man page again.